# tex4ht + tabu-package does not work

Tags: tex4ht, tabu

I am trying to compile an existing tex-document with tex4ht. However, it seems that the tabu-package does not work together with tex4ht:

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{tabu}

\begin{document}
Hallo
\end{document}
```

Already trying to load the tabu-package gives errors:

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.1415926-2.3-1.40.12 (MiKTeX 2.9) (preloaded format=latex  2012.8.13)  13 AUG 2012 15:58
entering extended mode
**\makeatletter\def\HCode{\futurelet\HCode\HChar}\def\HChar{\ifx\HCode\def\HCod
e##1{\Link##1}\expandafter\HCode\else\expandafter\Link\fi}\def\Link#1.a.b.c.{\g
@addto@macro\@documentclasshook{\RequirePackage[#1,html]{tex4ht}}\let\HCode\doc
umentstyle\def\documentstyle{\let\documentstyle\HCode\expandafter\def\csname te
x4ht\endcsname{#1,html}\def\HCode####1{\documentstyle[tex4ht,}\@ifnextchar[{\HC
ode}{\documentstyle[tex4ht]}}}\makeatother\HCode .a.b.c.\input  minimal.tex
(C:\Users\swilke\Documents\latex\Test\Testhtml\minimal.tex
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\base\book.cls"
Document Class: book 2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\base\bk10.clo"
File: bk10.clo 2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX file (size option)
)
... [Lots of lines omitted]

! Argument of \g:Advance has an extra }.
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: My feeling is that `tex4ht` needs adding support for the `tabu` environment; it must know about it and I guess it hasn't still found its way to the developers.